# How should I go on about updating a counter and price of my Items with React + Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

So far I can dispatch my items without a problem inside my InputItemName component using:

```
dispatch(addItem(name))
```

My displayItemsSlice looks like this:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const displayItemsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'displayItems',
  initialState: {
    itemList: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    addItem: (state, action) => {
      state.itemList.push({name: action.payload, counter: 1, price: 1});
    },
    addCounter: (state, action) => {
      console.log(state.itemList, action.payload)
    },
    addPrice: (state, action) => {
      return
    },
  },
})

export const { addItem, addCounter, addPrice} = displayItemsSlice.actions
export default displayItemsSlice.reducer
```

What I'm really struggling to do here is to update the counter for my item. I need a way to associate the payload of the counter with the correct item and update the object. With that done the price is just a matter of multiplying the counter * current price so it should be no problem.

Just let me know if any more info is necessary, I don't use Stack Overflow very often so I'm sorry in advance for the noob question but I'm struggling with this for weeks now.

ps: I'm using redux, react-redux and redux toolkit

edit: As it can be seen, the counter can be properly update on the display but not inside the redux state [image]

Comment: Can you add your view-code where you render this page?

Comment: Of course! By view-code do you mean the code itself? If not I will edit but here you go:

return (
    <div id="item-div">
      {console.log(itemList)}
      {itemList &&
        itemList.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.name}>
            <CheckCircle product={item.name}/>
            <span id={item.name} className="item-name">
              {item.name}
            </span>
            <Counter/>
            <AddPrice/>
          </div>
        ))}

had to delete some stuff because it was too long

Comment: if it was my console.log you were talking about:

Proxy {0: {…}}[[Handler]]: null[[Target]]: null[[IsRevoked]]: true 1

Comment: the code in these comments looks horrific, sorry about that :(

Comment: @fmagesty you're supposed to to add the code to the question, not the comment